# Adding a SetInterval function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, android-studio

So I have this code from here: [j360](https://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/jQuery-Plugin-For-Draggable-360-Degrees-Product-Image-View-j360.html)

This code is perfect for what I want: an html which has a draggable 360º product image view, but it lacks one thing: a button for auto rotation.

I already have the button into the html, but I can't, for more that I try, to make a function or anything to make the images go by itself, and not only when I drag it over the screen.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
(function($){
$.fn.j360 = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        clicked: false,
        currImg: 1
    }
    var options = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        var $obj = jQuery(this);
        var aImages = {};
        $obj.css({
            'margin-left' : 'auto',
            'margin-right' : 'auto',
            'text-align' : 'center',
            'overflow' : 'hide'
        });
        $overlay = $obj.clone(true);
        $overlay.html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loader" style="margin-top:' + ($obj.height()/2 - 15) + 'px" />');
        $overlay.attr('id', 'view_overlay');
        $overlay.css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'z-index': '5',
            'top' : $obj.offset().top,
            'left' : $obj.offset().left,
            'background' : '#fff'
        });
        $obj.after($overlay);
        $obj.after('<div id="colors_ctrls"></div>');
        jQuery('#colors_ctrls').css({
            'width' : $obj.width(),
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'z-index': '5',
            'top' : $obj.offset().top + $obj.height - 50,
            'left' : $obj.offset().left
        });
        var imageTotal = 0;
        jQuery('img', $obj).each(function() {
            aImages[++imageTotal] = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            preload(jQuery(this).attr('src'));
        })
        var imageCount = 0;
        jQuery('.preload_img').load(function() {
            if (++imageCount == imageTotal) {
                $overlay.animate({
                    'filter' : 'alpha(Opacity=0)',
                    'opacity' : 0
                }, 100);
                $obj.html('<img src="' + aImages[1] + '" />');
                $overlay.bind('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
                    if (e.type == "touchstart") {
                        options.currPos = window.event.touches[0].pageX;
                    } else {
                        options.currPos = e.pageX;
                    }
                    options.clicked = true;
                    return false;
                });
                jQuery(document).bind('mouseup touchend', function() {
                    options.clicked = false;
                });
                jQuery(document).bind('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
                    if (options.clicked) {
                        var pageX;
                        if (e.type == "touchmove") {
                            pageX = window.event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
                        } else {
                            pageX = e.pageX;
                        }
                        var width_step = 50;
                        if (Math.abs(options.currPos - pageX) >= width_step) {
                            if (options.currPos - pageX >= width_step) {
                                options.currImg++;
                                if (options.currImg > imageTotal) {
                                    options.currImg = 1;
                                }
                            } else {
                                options.currImg--;
                                if (options.currImg < 1) {
                                    options.currImg = imageTotal;
                                }
                            }
                            options.currPos = pageX;
                            $obj.html('<img src="' + aImages[options.currImg] + '" />');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        if (jQuery.browser.msie || jQuery.browser.mozilla || jQuery.browser.opera || jQuery.browser.safari ) {
            jQuery(window).resize(function() {
                onresizeFunc($obj, $overlay);
            });
        } else {
            var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
            orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";
            window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
                onresizeFunc($obj, $overlay);
            }, false);
        }
        onresizeFunc($obj, $overlay)
    });
}
})
(jQuery)


function onresizeFunc($obj, $overlay){

$obj.css({
    'margin-top' : $(document).height()/2
});
$overlay.css({
    'margin-top' : 200,
    'top' : $obj.offset().top,
    'left' : $obj.offset().left
});

jQuery('#colors_ctrls').css({
    'top' : $obj.offset().top + $obj.height - 50,
    'left' : $obj.offset().left
})
}

function preload(image) {

if (typeof document.body == "undefined") return;
try {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var s = div.style;
    s.position = "absolute";
    s.top = s.left = 0;
    s.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.innerHTML = "<img class=\"preload_img\" src=\"" + image + "\" />";
} 
catch(e) {
// Error. Do nothing.
}
};
```

I need a method to increment over time a function, to make the illusion of auto-rotate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Quote from [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293931/should-one-answer-terribly-poor-questions/293946#293946): "*We do not want debug-my-wall-of-code-for-me questions. Period. [...]*". Such questions are likely to get downvoted, closed and/or deleted. Try to reduce your code to a specific problem you've got by following the guidelines how to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes, you can’t ask question like this (do the job for me). You have to try and show what you have done. Also the title is not correct : it is not a simple button added with jQuery. You want to create a function.

Comment: Okey, I will try to edit now

Comment: In continuation of chade's comment and to help you on the way, try to reduce it to the actual "movement" (animation/rotation) of your object. If you reduce it to this point, it should be fairly easy to solve it. E.g. if you define the code that creates the actual movement/animation, you could wrap this in a `setInterval(function().....` or a `requestAnimationFrame`. In my opinion the `setInterval` is the easiest of those as the `rAF` requires a bit more coding and understanding, and might not yield such a big (if any) performance increase when you only manipulate the elements css.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin doesn’t seem to have this option (a kind of autoplay) so you have to code it or search an other plugin.

Since it is a list of image, you can maybe don’t use the plugin and display images one after another with jQuery and [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)